# Automate pivot table year over year price increase checks

Tags: excel, sorting, pivot-table

I am trying to use a pivot table on a large data set to understand if price increases went through to customers on orders of the same item number.

From left to right my rows are:
Customer name
Item number
Order year

The column I have is Sigma Values
and Sigma values is Average of price.

Not every item number has sales every year i.e. some customers might only have bought one item in 2018 and no orders since then, others have bought the same item in 2018, 2019 and 2020.

Any idea how I can sort this dataset to exclude any items that don't have multi year records?

Comment: Added Excel tag. Any ideas how to solve this?